# Specifying Quantity in Cart

Tags: aura

I'm working on a shopping cart feature. I'm trying allow users to specify the quantity of an item when it is added to the cart but also still allow users to increment by 1 when 'Add to Cart' is clicked.

The issue I am running into is that when I go to specify a quantity (i.e. 50) for an item in the input field but then click 'Add to Cart' again for the same item (1), the quantity becomes '501' rather than '51'. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's my cart component with a quantity input field:

```html
<aura:iteration items="{!v.cartItems}" var="cartItem" indexVar="index">
    <div class="slds-clearfix productRow">
        <div class="slds-float_left">
            {!cartItem.productName}
            <br/>
            Quantity: {!cartItem.quantity}
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning:input type="number" name="quantity"
                             label="Quantity"
                             value="{!cartItem.quantity}"
                             updateOn="keyup"
                             min="1"
                             max="500"
                             step="1"
                             messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Select a quantity between 1 and 500"
                             messageWhenRangeOverflow="Select a quantity between 1 and 500"
            />
        </div>     
        <div class="slds-float_right">
            <button class="slds-button" data-index="{!index}" onclick="{!c.onClickDelete}">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Here is the cart controller that allows users to increment each item:

```javascript
{
addedToCart: function (component, event, helper) {
    var cartItems = component.get('v.cartItems');
    var productAdded = event.getParam("product");
    productAdded = JSON.parse(productAdded);
    var itemAlreadyAdded=false;
    cartItems.forEach((Item) => {
        if(Item.productId == productAdded.productId){
            Item.quantity +=1;//incrementing
            itemAlreadyAdded=true;
        }
    });
    if(itemAlreadyAdded==false){
        cartItems.push(productAdded);
    }
    component.set('v.cartItems', cartItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use **parseInt**

```
 if(Item.productId == productAdded.productId){
            Item.quantity = parseInt(Item.quantity ) + parseInt(productAdded.quantity);
            itemAlreadyAdded=true;
        }
```